# How to escape `!$` in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, special-characters

There are a lot of questions on StackOverflow about how to escape a given character in `cmd.exe`. However it seems that none of the solutions work in my case.

Basically, what I want to do is to set the environment variable `FOO` to `a!$5`.

I tried the obvious:

```
set FOO=a!$5
```

Which gives:

```
History expansion: set FOO=ae5
```

Fair enough, I guess I have to escape the `!` or the `$`, or both. However nothing seems to work.

I can do:

```
echo a^!
a!
```

And:

```
echo a$
a$
```

And even:

```
echo a^$
a$
```

But:

```
echo a^!$
History expansion: echo a^a^$
aa$
```

I'm at loss figuring out what to do here. It seems no matter how I escape the special characters, I can't get the result I want.

How can I do that ?

Comment: The `$` sign is nothing special to `cmd`, so there is no reason to escape it; the `!` mark has only special meaning if [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a bug in [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/) which I have set-up on my computers.

I ended-up doing the boring, yet working:

```
set FOO=a!
set FOO=%FOO%$5
```

Which works perfectly. Sad but at least it works for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Escape each character with `^`: `echo a^!^$5`

`a!$5`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but when I type set FOO=a!$5, that's exactly what I get.  I thought it might require a predecessor

> **Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion**

but it worked without doing that (perhaps it is my default?) Sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: That is interesting. I'm now pretty sure it has to do with [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/) which I have set-up on my computer.

Comment: When you enable delayed expansion, literal exclamation marks `!` will get lost (or cause some other unexpected bahaviour)!